# AWS AppStream Fleet maximum Idle Disconnect Timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services

does anyone know if there is a way of setting the "Idle Disconnect Timeout" from an AppStream Fleet to value greater than 60min? The UI allows for a maximum of 60 minutes, but this is ridiculous for many applications.

I remember someone saying that you could bypass this by changing something in the registry, but I couldn't find any references about it.